# notepad++ regex - put numbers into brackets

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I have this list:

```
apple pie 14 1 60 100
orange 15 3 120 100
sweet cake 2 1 140 90
banana 1 2 0 0
```

and want to be like this:

```
('apple pie', '14', '1', '60', '100');
('orange', '15', '3', '120', '100');
('sweet cake', '2', '1', '140', '90');
('banana', '1', '2', '0', '0');
```

Regex is my "Achilles heel"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `([a-z ]+) (\d+) (\d+) (\d+) (\d+)` with `\('\1', '\2', '\3', '\4', '\5'\);`

Comment: I think you don't need the `\\` before the brackets in the replace expression.

Comment: Yes you do - I just tested it. Brackets are special characters for Regex and you need to escape them if you are referring to '(' or ')'.